# Mongodb startup issues

Tags: mongodb, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I am running into issues with mongodb startup. 
I have the below code in my chef repo:

```
cookbook_file "/etc/yum.repos.d/mongodb-org-4.2.repo" do
  source 'mongodb-org-4.2.repo'
  owner 'root'
  group 'root'
  mode 00644
end

yum_package 'mongodb-org' do
  action :install
  version '4.2.3-1.amzn2'
end

unless node['env']['is_dev']
  execute 'open mongo port' do
    command 'semanage port -a -t mongod_port_t -p tcp 27017'
    action :run
  end
end
```

Mongodb is failing with the below error:

```
================================================================================
    Error executing action `run` on resource 'execute[open mongo port]'
    ================================================================================
    Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed
    ------------------------------------
    Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'
    ---- Begin output of semanage port -a -t mongod_port_t -p tcp 27017 ----
    STDOUT: 
    STDERR: ValueError: Port tcp/27017 already defined
    ---- End output of semanage port -a -t mongod_port_t -p tcp 27017 ----
    Ran semanage port -a -t mongod_port_t -p tcp 27017 returned 1
    Resource Declaration:
    ---------------------
    # In /var/chef/local-mode-cache/cache/cookbooks/spinnaker-edda/recipes/install.rb
     51:   execute 'open mongo port' do
     52:     command 'semanage port -a -t mongod_port_t -p tcp 27017'
     53:     action :run
     54:   end
     55: end
```

Can anyone help me understanding what is going wrong here? 
I have read from the documentation that mongodb's default port is 27017. But I don't know why it's complaining.
I have also tried using `-m` instead of `-a` but the issue remains the same. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid if not strictly required to manually execute shell commands over target but always look first for some available valid cookbook that provides the required functionalities within a complex study of differents cases.
For your scenario you can use the **selinux_policy** cookbook ( look at https://github.com/sous-chefs/selinux_policy ).

Using that cookbook you can open mongo port as follow:

```
selinux_policy_permissive 27017 do
   action :add
end
```

About your issue it says `Port tcp/27017 already defined` so it means to the issue is that your instruction is not idempotent if the port is alrady defined on selinux. So using my suggested cookbook you should solve as probably it is idempotent within this scenario.